# Disappearing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have this `JPanel` (a) with `BoxLayout`.

When I add another `JPanel` (b) to it, with `setPreferredSize()` and `setBackground()`, it gets drawn nicely on (a). However, if I `setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)` on (b), it doesn't get drawn at all. Or added, I cannot be sure.

If I use other layout manager (e.g. `BorderLayout`), it appears again.

Anybody care to explain?

Comment: What is the class where you set the new BoxLayout(this, ...) ?

Comment: (b) is actually a class that extends JPanel, but it doesn't really do anything except written above. Comenting out setlayout command triggers the change (see me - don't see me)
BTW, It's the boxlayout, if I set it to e.g. borderlayout, it works...

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemes that other components (with null layout) added to same parent got in the way. Setting a layout different from null to all the children of parent component fixes the issue, and keeps the layout to look as if they were all null layout...